# How does a Node server subscribe correctly to a Redis channel with Laravel 8?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-8

In Laravel 8, I generate a broadcast event that writes data to Redis.

The broadcastOn method of the "NewEvent implements ShouldBroadcast" class specifies the name of the event that writes data to Redis.

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['news-action'];
}
```

With the help of the redis-cli monitor, I can see the format of the data that goes to the Redis server.

```
1616158237.374187 [0 127.0.0.1:60746] "SELECT" "0"
1616158237.374770 [0 127.0.0.1:60746] "EVAL" "for i = 2, #ARGV do\n  redis.call('publish', ARGV[i], ARGV[1])\nend" "0" "{\"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\NewEvent\",\"data\":{\"result\":{\"labels\":[\"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\",\"\\u0430\\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\",\"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0439\",\"\\u0438\\u044e\\u043d\\u044c\",\"33333\"],\"datasets\":[{\"label\":\"\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\\u0436\\u0438\",\"backgroundColor\":[\"#D01919\",\"#F26202\",\"#EAAE00\",\"#B5CC18\"],\"data\":[15000,50000,10000,8000,500]}]},\"socket\":null},\"socket\":null}" "laravel_database_news-action"
1616158237.374850 [0 lua] "publish" "laravel_database_news-action" "{\"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\NewEvent\",\"data\":{\"result\":{\"labels\":[\"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\",\"\\u0430\\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\",\"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0439\",\"\\u0438\\u044e\\u043d\\u044c\",\"33333\"],\"datasets\":[{\"label\":\"\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\\u0436\\u0438\",\"backgroundColor\":[\"#D01919\",\"#F26202\",\"#EAAE00\",\"#B5CC18\"],\"data\":[15000,50000,10000,8000,500]}]},\"socket\":null},\"socket\":null}"
```

Since this data is incomprehensible to a person in this form, I tried to parse it manually, and that's what I got.

```
1616158237.374187 [0 127.0.0.1:60746] "SELECT" "0"
1616158237.374770 [0 127.0.0.1:60746] "EVAL" "for i = 2, #ARGV do\n  redis.call('publish', ARGV[i], ARGV[1])\nend" "0"
"{
    \"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\NewEvent\",
    \"data\":{
        \"result\":{
            \"labels\":[
                \"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\",
                \"\\u0430\\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\",
                \"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0439\",
                \"\\u0438\\u044e\\u043d\\u044c\",
                \"33333\"
            ],
            \"datasets\":[
                {
                    \"label\":\"\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\\u0436\\u0438\",
                    \"backgroundColor\":[
                        \"#D01919\",
                        \"#F26202\",
                        \"#EAAE00\",
                        \"#B5CC18\"
                    ],
                    \"data\":[
                        15000,50000,10000,8000,500
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        \"socket\":null
    },
    \"socket\":null
}"
"laravel_database_news-action"
1616158237.374850 [
    0 lua
]
"publish"
"laravel_database_news-action"
"{
    \"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\NewEvent\",
    \"data\":{
        \"result\":{
            \"labels\":[
                \"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0440\\u0442\",
                \"\\u0430\\u043f\\u0440\\u0435\\u043b\\u044c\",
                \"\\u043c\\u0430\\u0439\",
                \"\\u0438\\u044e\\u043d\\u044c\",
                \"33333\"
            ],
            \"datasets\":[
                {
                    \"label\":  \"\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0434\\u0430\\u0436\\u0438\",
                    \"backgroundColor\":[\"#D01919\",\"#F26202\",\"#EAAE00\",\"#B5CC18\"],
                    \"data\":[15000,50000,10000,8000,500]
                }
            ]
        },
        \"socket\":null
    },
    \"socket\":null
}"
```

My Node server correctly subscribes to the Redis channel "*"

```
redis.psubscribe("*", (err, count) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Failed to subscribe: %s", err.message);
    } else {
        console.log(
            `Subscribed successfully! This client is currently subscribed to ${count} channels.`
        );
    }
});
```

and issues a message about it to the console.

```
$ node node-server.js
Listening on Port: 3000
Subscribed successfully! This client is currently subscribed to 1 channels.
```

The Node server then connects to the socket.

```
redis.on("pmessage", (channel, message) => {
    console.log(channel);
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
```

But for some reason, not the message itself gets into the variable "message", but this text "laravel_database_news-action" which I see in the console

```
$ node node-server.js
Listening on Port: 3000
Subscribed successfully! This client is currently subscribed to 1 channels.
*
laravel_database_news-action
```

Because of this, during an attempt to pass this string in the JSON.parse (message) function, the Node-server immediately crashes.

From this I conclude that at the time of subscribing to the channel, I must indicate the specific name of the channel, but not "*"

But if I change "*" to "news-action" then the server stops responding and does not output any messages to the console.

Therefore, I want to know how to specify the channel name correctly so that the subscription is performed correctly and that the correct data, which is written in Redis server, gets into the variable "message"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, everybody, I figured it out.

First, I added another method in the "Broadcast" class of the event.

```
public function broadcastAs(){
    return 'new-event';
}
```

Secondly, fixed some functions in my Node server.

If suddenly someone needs it, then I represent him completely.

```
const http =  require('http').Server();
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        // origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        // methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        // withCredentials: false
    }
});
const Redis = require('ioredis');

const redis = new Redis(6379, "127.0.0.1");

redis.psubscribe("*", (err, count) => {
    //
});

redis.on("pmessage", (pattern, channel, message) => {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    // console.log(pattern);
    // console.log(channel);
    // console.log(message);
    io.emit("news-action:"+message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log('Listening on Port: 3000')
});
```

And thirdly, the client must subscribe to the channel as follows

```
socket.on("news-action:new-event", function (data){
    // console.log(data);
    this.data = data.result;
}.bind(this));
```